# Java: sorting an ArrayList in place

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

In Java's standard library, is there a method that would allow one to sort an `ArrayList` in place, i.e. using `O(1)` extra storage?

[`Collections.sort(List<T>)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) does not fulfil this requirement since it

> dumps the specified list into an array, sorts the array, and iterates over the list resetting each element from the corresponding position in the array.

If there's nothing in the standard library, what third-party libraries can be used to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can extract the underlying array (e.g. reflection) and perform a Arrays.sort(array, 0, list.size()) on it.

Java 7 does not copy the array in Arrays.sort() before sorting the array. In Java 6 it does which means that Collections.sort() in Java 6 actually copies the underlying array TWICE to perform the sort.

Comment: Only thing is this takes a copy of the array and so uses O(n) extra storage as per Collections.sort.

Comment: In Java 7 it doesn't take a copy. I haven't checked Java 6.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm actually pretty surprised they've changed the behaviour to return the underlying array; can imagine this would cause lots of subtle bugs for people upgrading from Java 6.

Comment: Arrays.sort() doesn't return anything. The question is whether it copies the array before sorting it.

Comment: In Java 8 `Collections.sort` calls `sort` on the list, so it's up to the list implementation. `ArrayList` calls `Arrays.sort` with its element array, so that is still in place.

Answer (score 1):

`Collections.sort()` was made to work with any List implementation, and that's why it's not working in place (merging LinkedList in place is difficult and sacrifices stability).

If you are really worried about sorting in-place you'll have to roll out your own sort funcion. It's not really worth your time unless your List is very long.

`Arrays.sort(Object[])` does the same mergesort and is called internally by `Collections.sort()` (at least in openjdk)

Comment: you can do copy-pasta of the heapsort described here, using ArrayList instead of array: [link]http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Sorting/Heapsort)

Answer (score 1):

As of Java 8 `List` interface has default `void sort(Comparator<? super E> c)` API, using which you can sort an instance in place.

The list must be modifiable, iterable and its elements comparable to each other.